# Spring @ResponseBody returns JSON, but keys are missing

Tags: json, spring, hibernate

I'm returning the results of a SQL query in JSON format. The result is ok, but the keys (columns specified in the query) are missing. Do I have to associate a class with the query in order to get key names? I don't think it's the Jackson Mapping since when I use it explicitly (object mapper instead of letting Spring handle it in the @ResponseBody) I get the same result.

Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 3.6. Using Hibernate createSQLQuery to get results from 5 tables.

```
List<EvalMasterEvalDetail> details = session.createSQLQuery(query).list();
```

Result looks like:

```
[[61,"Conference","CME Conference"],[42,"Lecture","fellow lecture"]]
```

Should be

```
[[{"detail_id":61, "event_type":"Conference", "event_name":"CME Conference"}],
[{"detail_id":42, "event_type":"Lecture", "event_name":"fellow lecture"}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default SQL query in Hibernate returns a list of scalar values (for single column in `select`) or a list of `Object[]` (for multiple columns).

You have the latter case. `List<EvalMasterEvalDetail>` in this case doesn't mean that list contains instances of `EvalMasterEvalDetail`, because `list()` returns a raw `List`, so that you have unchecked conversion.

If each tuple of result represents a mapped entity (or multiple mapped entities), you can use [`addEntity()` and `addJoin()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html) to convert them to entities.

If each tuple of result represents an arbitrary (non-mapped) class, you can use `ResultTransformer` (such as [`AliasToBeanResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)).

Also you can convert `Object[]`s to target objects manually (useful in complex cases).

Comment: How can I add addEntity to JPA Repository @Query?

Answer (score 0):

you can prepare a JSONObject or a list of JSONObject by iterating over your list and return to client as String.